# Time difference in query

Tags: sql, date, amazon-redshift

I am trying to run this query to find some field form redshift and extra column as time difference. Below I have mentioned the query which I am trying to execute.

```
select gtfs.t_stops_gtfs.*, gtfs.t_stop_times_gtfs.departure_time, '${currentTime}' as current_time, 
   datediff(minute, gtfs.t_stop_times_gtfs.departure_time, '${currentTime}') as td from gtfs.t_stops_gtfs 
   join gtfs.t_stop_times_gtfs on gtfs.t_stops_gtfs.stop_id = gtfs.t_stop_times_gtfs.stop_id limit 3
```

The error which I am getting is

> function pg_catalog.date_diff("unknown", character varying, "unknown") does not exist

any idea whats wrong in this.

Erorr is coming because of this line `datediff(minute, gtfs.t_stop_times_gtfs.departure_time, '${currentTime}') as td`

sample value in  departure_time: '18:25:00', current_time: '06:34:39'`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html) the datediff function need as input two timestamp or datetime. As you can see in your error, `gtfs.t_stop_times_gtfs.departure_time` passed is parsed  as a string and `'${currentTime}'` is of type unknown. What you have to do is to cast them as date or timestamp like:

```
datediff(minute, gtfs.t_stop_times_gtfs.departure_time::date, '${currentTime}'::date)
```